# Does wearing a focus keep your hands free?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, ranger, spellcasting-focus

So the text for the [Nature's Mantle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/natures-mantle) in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* states:

> while wearing the cloak, you can use it as a focus for your druid and ranger spells." Other foci specify "while holding the focus.

So does mean that by wearing it you do not need a hand free to access mundane material components?
Thank you!

Comment: Was wondering about this, and same for using a Genie's Vessel ring (with a compartment) as a focus for a warlock with Genie as a patron (Tasha's pg 73-74).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Only if the spell does not also have somatic components.

So the general rule is this:

> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell's material components — or to hold a spellcasting focus — but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.

The Nature's Mantle creates an exception to this rule when it says:

> While wearing the cloak, you can use it as a spellcasting focus for your druid and ranger spells.

You don't have to hold it in hand, the only condition for its use is "while wearing the cloak".

*But this does not excuse somatic components*:

> Spellcasting gestures might include a forceful gesticulation or an intricate set of gestures. If a spell requires a somatic component, the caster must have free use of at least one hand to perform these gestures.

So if the spell requires both S and M components, you still need a free hand to perform the S components. If the Spell is [(V,M)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-verbal=t&filter-somatic=f&filter-material=t&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=), then the cloak allows you to cast the spell hands-free.